# jquery datepicker allows date less than minDate

Tags: jquery, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have a datepicker and it can not allow dates prior to today VIA the editbox.

```
var dateOptions = { 
  dateFormat: "mm/dd/yy", 
  constrainInput: true, 
  gotoCurrent: true, 
  minDate: new Date()
};

$('.date').datepicker(dateOptions);
$('.date').datepicker('setDate', new Date());
```

In the html it's implemented as:

```
<label class="text14"><strong>Depart</strong></label>
<input type="text" id="tbDTimeOne" maxlength="10" size="10" name="tbDTimeOne" class="colum130 date" /> <img src="images/calendar.png" style="margin-left:-25px;" />
```

OK, so here's what happens.  The page gets rendered, the onready function gets called, date input gets set to todays date, user tabs/clicks to the date input, the calendar pops up, the user edits the existing date via the keyboard and sets it to a date prior to today, the user tabs to the next field.  The input accepted and shown is a date prior to the minDate.

What's the solution to this?

Comment: Make the input field readonly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Datepicker does not restrict keyboard input (see http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/6917)

```
$('.date').attr('readonly', 'readonly');
```

would be a solution, but then you'll lose the possibility to enter text by Hand. 
If you need to keep this functionality, you can still validate the input
http://keith-wood.name/uiDatepickerValidation.html

Comment: Thanks.  Using the minDate along with the validator seems like the only real solution.  I'm surprised that jquery doesn't just beep when the user tries to enter a date less than minDate or minimally validate onClose or provide a callback.

Answer (score 0):

http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker#option-minDate

```
minDate: new Date(2011,12,30)
```

Comment: We're alaready setting the minDate. Keyboard input is apparently ignored (not validated).

Answer (score 0):

Another possible option to this is to use an Input Mask.  With the inputs/jQuery you can use the .Mask prototype and forces the user to enter the valid date format you're looking for.  You can also use the moment.js library to use a custom combinations of validations as well.

```
$(".someClass").mask("00/00/0000");
```

This will force a date of 01/01/2017, instead of 1/1/1 which gets the date value confused in the JS.